# Retrieving Text from Textbox in dynamically Created UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

Im creating a survey page, this page pulls from the database to display questions based on their type, For each type I have created a user control. At `Page_Load`, I place the User Control in a placeholder like this:- (QNO is a session i set to 0 on the previous page, just to start the question order)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection Connection = DatabaseConnection.GetSurveySystemConnection();

            string sqlquery = "SELECT Q.[ID], Q.[Question_Order], Q.[Question], QT.[Type_Desc] FROM [Questions] Q Inner join Question_Type QT On Q.Type_ID= QT.ID Where Q.[Survey_ID] =" + Session["Survey_ID"] + "Order by Question_Order";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, Connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(DT);

            if (DT != null)
            {
                Session["Count"] = DT.Rows.Count;
                QuestionLabel.Text = String.Format("{0}.{1}", DT.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QNO"])]["Question_Order"].ToString(), DT.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QNO"])]["Question"].ToString());
                Session["Question_ID"] = DT.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QNO"])]["ID"].ToString();

                if (DT.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QNO"])]["Type_Desc"].ToString() == "Multiple Choice")
                {
                    Control uc = Page.LoadControl("UserControls/MultipleChoice.ascx");
                    PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(uc);
                }
                else if (DT.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QNO"])]["Type_Desc"].ToString() == "Single Choice")
                {
                    Control uc = Page.LoadControl("UserControls/SingleChoice.ascx");
                    PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(uc);
                }
                else if (DT.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QNO"])]["Type_Desc"].ToString() == "Yes/No")
                {
                    Control uc = Page.LoadControl("UserControls/YesOrNo.ascx");
                    PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(uc);
                }
                else if (DT.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QNO"])]["Type_Desc"].ToString() == "Agree/Disagree")
                {
                    Control uc = Page.LoadControl("UserControls/AgreeDisagree");
                    PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(uc);
                }
                else if (DT.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QNO"])]["Type_Desc"].ToString() == "Rating")
                {
                    Control uc = Page.LoadControl("UserControls/Rating.ascx");
                    PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(uc);
                }
                else if (DT.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Session["QNO"])]["Type_Desc"].ToString() == "Open Ended")
                {
                    Control uc = Page.LoadControl("UserControls/OpenEnded.ascx");
                    PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(uc);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now, lets say for the type "Open Ended", it displays a textbox in the `usercontrol`, I want to access this textbox and retrieve the text inside it and put it in another textbox at the push of a button, I created a static textbox on the page and called it `ViewTextBox`.
This is what i tried:-

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    TextBox t = Controls[0].Controls[3].Controls[11].Controls[5].Controls[0].Controls[0] as TextBox;
    ViewTextBox.Text = t.Text; //"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
            }
```

Any Ideas? I dug my way through the controls on the page to find the textbox in the usercontrol :-

```
Response.Write(Controls[0].Controls[3].Controls[11].Controls[5].Controls[0].Controls[0].ID);
```

And the ID comes up as the textbox im looking for. The textbox in the usercontrol is called "OpenEndedTextBox"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of digging like that, I would suggest creating a `Method or Property in your user control` to get that text from your User Control like this

```
public string GetAnsweredText()
{
   return this.AnswerTextBox.Text;
}
```

and call this Method in your button's click event in your page containing that user control like this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   UC_SurveyControl control = this.Controls[0] as UC_SurveyControl;
   if (control != null)
       string answer = control.GetAnsweredText();
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error on that line?

Comment: @BasharAl-Khalili most likely the control you are trying to find is not exist at that index you are trying to get it from. That's why I suggest you to create that method so that you don't have to find it iterating over those indices.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use recursion here it's might be not the best performance solution, but it's works perfectly.

This is should used in `Page_PreRender()` event.

```
 public static T FindControlRecursive<T>(Control sourceControl, string targetControlId) 
  where T : class    
{    
   if (sourceControl == null)    
     throw new ArgumentNullException("sourceControl");    
   if (targetControlId == null)    
     throw new ArgumentNullException("targetControlId");    
   if (sourceControl.ID == targetControlId) return sourceControl as T;    
   foreach (Control control in sourceControl.Controls)    
   {    
     T controlToReturn = FindControlRecursive<T>(control, targetControlId);    
     if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn as T;    
   }    
   return null;    
}
```

Si vis pacem DotNetnum.